# Can you give me an example of constant onto function

Tags: functions

What I think is a  function which is constant but onto should just have the single value in codomain which the function takes

Comment: yes, you are correct

Answer (score 2):

So the codomain must have only $1$ element:   $f:C\to D$, where $D=\{x_0\}$.  $C$, the domain, on the other hand,  can be any nonempty set.  So $f(x)=x_0\,,\forall x\in C$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=\{2\},$ and define $f:A \to B$ by $f(x)=2$ for any integer $x.$